# xception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-4

I am new to asp.net and using the Entity framework. We have to create a website that use an entity model. The entity model (database) we exported as a .dll to be used by a asp.net website. When I call a function that uses a function of the dll I receive the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
```

The model was created with the entityframework version 4.0.0.0. The oldest version that I could add to the asp.net website is version 4.2.0.0. I am not sure if this is the cause or if it is something else. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your config? Class libraries don't have configs, the web project needs to have the appropriate entity framework configuration. I think that may be your problem.

Comment: The entity framework configuration seems to be correct in both programs(the dll and website) there is a reference to System.Data.Entity and both of those references are of version 4.0.0.0. As a side note, should the database used to create the model exist after the model is created?

Comment: That might be the problem. I created the dll using a computer that had sql server installed and thus connect to localhost. But the computer I am currently using uses sqlexpress (.\SQLExpress to connect). Do I need to change the connection string then?

Comment: yes you do, to .\SQLExpress. And you need to publish your database, if you've not already done so (if your not using code first EF)